# Оптимизация кода в python

Tags: python, оптимизация

Я решал задачку [«Покупка футболок»](http://codeforces.com/contest/799/problem/B), но оказалось, что она работает очень медленно. Причин я не могу понять, так как не слишком хорошо знаю питон. Но одно я понимаю точно, что это странно, так как оно имеет хорошую ассимптотику и не должно долго работать.

```
n = int(raw_input())
price = [int(value) for value in raw_input().split(' ')]
front = [1 << (int(value) - 1) for value in raw_input().split(' ')]
back = [1 << (3 + int(value) - 1) for value in raw_input().split(' ')]
result = {}
for index in range(0, n):
    if not(front[index] + back[index] in result):
        result[front[index] + back[index]] = [price[index]]
    else:
        result[front[index] + back[index]].append(price[index])
for item in result:
    result[item] = sorted(result[item])
cust = int(raw_input())
fav = [1 << (int(value) - 1) for value in raw_input().split(' ')]

index = 0
for itemCust in fav:
    minValue = 2000000000
    minItem = -1
    for item in result:
        priceValue = result[item]
        if (item & itemCust != 0 or item & (itemCust << 3) != 0) and len(priceValue) > 0 and priceValue[0] < minValue:
            minValue = priceValue[0]
            minItem = item
    if minItem != -1:
        result[minItem] = result[minItem][1:]
        print minValue
    else:
        print -1
```

*Комментарий по задаче*. У нас есть пары чиселок от 1 до 3 (футболки). Есть запросы (покупатели) в виде одной чиселки от 1 до 3, которым важно, чтобы среди пар чиселок (футболок) была хотя бы одна такая же, как и у них.

Для решения мы кидаем все футболки в мапу, кодируя их следующим образом. Каждая футболка -- это бит-число из 2х единиц. Первые 3 единицы отвечают первой чиселке из пары. Вторые 3 единицы отвечают второй чиселке из пары.

```
1 1 --> 100100 (т.е. 1ый бит и (1 + 3)ый бит)

1 2 --> 100010 (т.е. 1ый бит и (2 + 3)ый бит)

3 2 --> 001010 (т.е. 3ий бит и (2 + 3)ый бит)
```

и т.д.

Собственно, для каждого бинарного кода заведём мапу и будем хранить список цен, отсортированных в порядке убывания. После чего переберём всех покупателей поочереди и будем выбирать за 6 шагов самую подходящую футболку.

Comment: А вопрос в чем? Вы можете посмотреть на узкие места в вашем коде, используя профилировщики: [vmprof](https://vmprof.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), [kernprof](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler)

Comment: @m9_psy Вопрос в том, где могут быть узкие места в коде. Окей, погляжу.

Comment: вам эти инструменты покажут все узкие места лучше любого ответа - они покажут сколько времени (сколько раз) выполняется та или иная строчка в вашем скрипте (не как cProfile - тот сразу в потроха лезет) - отсюда можно и оценивать асимптотику (сколько раз вызывается та или иная функция в зависимости от входных данных) и насколько тяжела та или иная операция и чем ее можно заменить.

Comment: @m9_psy, это, конечно, всё прекрасно, но ассимптотика и так понятна, ровно как и примерное число операций. Непонятность во времени добавления и извеления данных из структуры `dict` и сортировках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот решение в лоб за 2,2 сек

```
import time
import random

# исходные данные
shirts_count = 200000
shirts_prices = [random.randrange(1, 1000000000) for _ in range(shirts_count)]
shirts_colors_front = [random.randrange(1, 3) for _ in range(shirts_count)]
shirts_colors_back = [random.randrange(1, 3) for _ in range(shirts_count)]

shoppers_count = shirts_count - 1
shoppers_colors = [random.randrange(1, 3) for _ in range(shoppers_count)]

# {цвета: [цены]}
Shirts = {}
for c, p in zip(zip(shirts_colors_front, shirts_colors_back), sorted(shirts_prices)):
    try: Shirts[c].append(p)
    except: Shirts[c] = [p]

def buy_color_shirt(color: int):
    '''купить'''
    for c in Shirts:
        if color in c:
            prices = Shirts[c]
            if prices:
                return prices.pop(0)
    return -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = time.time()
    # покупка
    for color in shoppers_colors:
        buy_color_shirt(color)
    print(round(time.time() - t, 1), 'сек')
```